# Simplest embedding of Python in C++ under Linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, gcc

I am having problems with embedding the Python in C++ under Linux (Ubuntu).

I use g++ with the following version:

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
```

So, here is the following model problem:

I would like to compile the following simple cpp-file (the one from official docs [docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html][1]), here called **testPy.cpp**:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

My Python directory is in **/home/unpix/anaconda3**

Now, I compile this file by command:

```
g++ testPy.cpp -c $(/home/unpix/anaconda3/bin/python3.8-config --cflags)
```

O.K., it creates **testPy.o**. Now linking:

```
g++ testPy.o $(/home/unpix/anaconda3/bin/python3.8-config --ldflags --embed ) -fno-lto
```

It works also, it creates **a.out**

Note that if the last command would be without -fno-lto, it would end with an error:

```
lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file ‘/home/unpix/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a’ generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 8.1
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

BUT. When I run the file **a.out**, the output is not what I wanted, it is the following:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = './a.out'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/home/unpix/Documents/testPy/testCppPy/a.out'
  sys.base_prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.executable = '/home/unpix/Documents/testPy/testCppPy/a.out'
  sys.prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'
  sys.path = [
    '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python38.zip',
    '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/python3.8',
    '/tmp/build/80754af9/python_1599203911753/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f405b71e180 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I was not able to find any solution anywhere.
So, what am I doing wrong? Thank You all in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to find solutions? I found plenty of info on this error. Do you mean none of the solutions you saw worked? Which ones did you try? You should specify that. Did you try any of the solutions [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue27054)?

Comment: @RandomDavis First of all, thank You for the comment. To be honest, I haven't find much info about this error. I tried to play with the variable PYTHONHOME, (as suggested in your link), but still the same error. But well, at least now I know (if I understand it correct) that the problem lies in Python, not  calling g++ with wrong parameters or wrong c++ code.